# Calling from a contract function within another contract via the original caller (using WETH in a contract)

Tags: solidity

I have a smart contract that uses WETH for trading. I am testing on my local and I deploy a WETH smart contract, the source code: [source code](https://etherscan.io/address/0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2#code)

I can successfully access the WETH contract from my contract like this:

```
function testMint() payable public {
    WETH.approve(address(this), msg.value);
}
```

I am calling testMint via Externally Owned Account (EOA), and I also want to access WETH.approve via the same caller. In above scenario, msg.sender of testMint is not the msg.sender of WETH.approve therefore approve function provides allowance "from contract to contract" not "from EOA to contract". Is there any way to call WETH.approve function with the EAO caller. I would appreciate with any help.

Comment: That is not possible. Only the EOA can call approve on  its behalf.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a way, for example using `tx.origin` in the WETH contract. But it is not a good practice to do.

Also, `approve` is always a separate transaction. So you have to approve your funds first, only then can you execute `testMint()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way using modifier,

```
modifier addApprove(uint _amount) {
     WETH.approve(address(this), amount);
     _;        
}

function testMint()  public addApprove(100) {

}
```